# How do I redirect my tax refund to a different bank account for direct deposit after I already filed?

Tags: united-states, taxes, electronic-filing

What happens or what can I do?

I filed electronically and had it sent to direct deposit, but then found out card was not active. But I have another account to send it to.

What do I do? I know how to take care of the state. But it's the federal.

Comment: What card are you talking about that's not active?  Direct deposit on Form 1040, Line 76 goes to a bank account not any card. (Your bank account might or might not be linked to a debit card, but that's a separate issue.)

Comment: No it was a Accountnow but I thought it was still active but to my surprise it isn't. They got my state check yesterday but sent it back.and the federal is supposed to be in there tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there isn't anything you can do at this point.  What will happen is that the IRS will attempt to deposit the refund and that deposit attempt will fail.  The funds will be transferred back to the IRS and then the IRS will issue you a check.  It'll probably take a few weeks for the check to arrive.